# beautifulsoup - how i remove js code in my crawling data?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i use find_all but there is some problem on my data.
i only need text, but js script was copied too
crawled js data is like this.
how can i remove this?

```
window.__mugFnList__.push(function() {            !function($, window) {                if (mug.common.isDev()) {                    console.log("asyncGet funding");                }                function asyncGet() {                    $.ajax({                        url: "getSe3FundingView.nhn",                        dataType:"html",                        data: {                            authorNo: "11166748",                            seriesNo: "368342"                        },                        success: function(resultHtml){                            if (mug.common.isDev()) {                                console.log("asyncGet funding success!!");                            } $.trim(resultHtml);                            $("#__tmp_fundingView").replaceWith(resultHtml);                            $(window).trigger("viewerFundingLoad");                        },                        error: function(resp) {                            console.log(resp);                        }                    });                }                $(window).load(function() {                    setTimeout(asyncGet, 1);                });            }(jQuery, window);        });        
    window.__mugFnList__.push(function() {
        !function($, window) {
            if (mug.common.isDev()) {
                console.log("asyncGet event");
            }
            function asyncGet() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "getEventView.nhn",
                    dataType:"html",
                    data: {
                        volumeNo: "13440747",
                        memberNo: "11166748"
                    },
                    success: function(resultHtml){
                        if (mug.common.isDev()) {
                            console.log("asyncGet event success!!");
                        }
 $.trim(resultHtml);
                        $("#__tmp_eventView").replaceWith(resultHtml);
 "") {
                            try {window.__viewer._resizePan();}catch(e){};
                        }
                        $(window).trigger("viewerEventLoad");
                    },
                    error: function(resp) {
                        console.log(resp);
                    }
                });
            }
            $(window).load(function() {
                setTimeout(asyncGet, 1);
            });

        }(jQuery, window);
    });
```

Comment: You can remove all `<script>` tags before parsing your data.

Comment: @AndrejKesely umm... Please give more detailed explanation.js code has no <tag>

Comment: You cannot parse Javascript with BeautifulSoup, BeautifulSoup is for parsing HTML/XML documents

Comment: can you add the code snippet you have developed?